# How to print all Webform messages outside the form?

Tags: 7, theming, webforms

Does anybody knows how to print all messages (confirmations or error messages) outside the form (created using the [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module, for example right after the body tag?

I've changed the markup of my alerts. I want them to be full screen, but I can't achieve this, when they're inside the form.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Webform is working on drupal default message

```
<?php if ($messages): ?>
  <div id="messages"><div class="section clearfix">
    <?php print $messages; ?>
  </div></div> <!-- /.section, /#messages -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

You need to put this code according to your requirement on the template (page.tpl.php).

Finally, webform submission thank you message will be shown on your content section which is coming on node.tpl.php

```
<?php print $links; ?>
```